# Connect RPi 3 running Windows IOT to PLC through Ethernet or RS232/485

Tags: ethernet, windows-iot

I want to connect my RPi 3 running Windows IOT to any PLC through whatever (prefer industrial connections) like Ethernet or RS232 or RS485 to control temperature sensor and display it on 7 inch touch screen LCD connecting to RPi 3 !
sound's odd but any suggestion would be so helpful 
?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

Write a `Windows Universal App` using Visual Studio Community (or Professional if your business will fork out the expense - recommended)

You must work out how you want to or how you "can" connect to your PLC in the first place. It may have a IP/LAN interface? Maybe RS232? We do not know, get the technical details from the manufacture and the protocol specification.

Then in C# you write your implementation. IP would be easier than UART (RS232) as it is easier to do webrequests or API requests in a single line where UART requires a bit more setting up, etc.

Then you can deploy your UWA to any Windows 10 machine, like a Phone/ Tablet or in this case dedicated Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Kepware IoT Gateway.  It can proved PLC data through a REST interface as a Client or Server.  REST Server for one shot writes and reads.  The Kepware IoT Gateway RESTful Client can be used to post real-time data changes to a a RESTfull Service running on the Windows 10 IoT Core device.